# Execute JS on all sites on page load

Tags: javascript

I need to execute JS code after loading all/specified pages in browser (i.e. predefined code). Which browsers and their plugins/component provide to implement it?

Manual way is open console (e.g. firebug) and execute. I want to do it automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery?  Assuming I understand your question correctly

Comment: This isn't very clear... Why not load the JS from your web-server (so it runs automatically)?

Comment: I don't have access to server. I need to execute custom code on all visited pages in browser instead my sites or server. Simple example if idea is not clear: remove advertisment using JS for any visited page, but i need solution for another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely automated, but a [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) will let you run your JavaScript by clicking an item in your bookmark bar.

For complete automation locally in your browser (asuming Firefox since you mention Firebug) you should look for addons which solves your particular need. [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for example is very useful.